# Removing unicode <U+????> from all observations in a column

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame of twitter tweets in one column which have various unicodes throughout the text. i.e. not at the beginning or end, but randomly throughout. I want to only remove all the Unicodes from the `text` column and preserve the data frame. For instance if one observation is:  `text text <U+FFH5> text text <U+301F> text`  I would like it to return: `text text text text text`

I have attempted:

```
twitter <- str_replace_all(twitter,"<U+[[:alnum:]]>","") 

twitter <- gsub("\\s*<U\\+\\w+>$","",twitter)
```

As well as:

```
twitter$text <- str_replace_all(twitter$text,"<U+[[:alnum:]]>","") 

twitter$text <- gsub("\\s*<U\\+\\w+>$","",twitter$text)
```

They do not preserve the data frame.

my data frame currently looks like :

```
id    text
AA    Some text<U+FFFD>with some <U+671F> done
HH    <U+3010><U+5B9A><U+671F>good news
AA    Something<U+FFFD><U+FFFD>and so on
BB    Nothing at <U+3011>
AA    more<U+30C8>example
```

Which I would like to convert to:

```
id    text
AA    Some text with some  done
HH    good news
AA    Something and so on
BB    Nothing at
AA    more example
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Are you sure the string "<U+301F>" is literally in the text? Or are you using a viewer that is escaping the non-ascii character to make it printable.

Comment: Which client are you using? That's almost certainly ONE Unicode character that doesn't need replacing. The only reason you see it this way is that the client can't dispaly non-ASCII characters properly, or the settings specify to display the encoded value instead of the character itself. For example R Studio needs to be configured to use UTF8 for reading/writing *and* displaying

Comment: Another warning - `U+FFFD` corresponds to the Unicode replacement character. It appears when the code tries to load text that's stored in one codepage using another, incompatible one. That data is *lost*. Where does this text come from? How is it generated, saved, read ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (partly based on [Remove all text between two brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966678/remove-all-text-between-two-brackets)):

```
twitter ="text <> text <U+FFH5> text text <U+301F> text"

str_replace_all(twitter,"\\<U[^\\>]*\\>","") # only removes unicode
```

Comment: I just attempted to apply this to my data frame `twitter' as:  `twitter <- str_replace_all(twitter,"\\<U[^\\>]*\\>","")` and it reduced my data frame into a `Large character (2 elements, 3.5 Mb)`

Comment: As someone mentioned in the comments, are you **sure** this character sequence exists? That it isn't how R presents a *single* Unicode character>

Comment: Not sure how you are trying to replace the values. Are you changing `twitter$text = str_replace_all(twitter$text,"\\<U[^\\>]*\\>","")`