# Removing substring from a string in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string something like this:

```
OPEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 [19BVEO     345.00] TO BUS 
264888 [19LRTY     345.00] CKT 1
```

I would like to remove the substring enclosed between "[" and "]". The result should be something like this:

```
OPEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 TO BUS 264888 CKT 1
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`:

```
s='OPEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 [19BVEO     345.00] TO BUS 264888 [19LRTY     345.00] CKT 1'

pieces=[s.split(']')[-1] for s in s.split('[')]
print(pieces)
['OPEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 ', ' TO BUS 264888 ', ' CKT 1']

sentence=''.join(pieces)
print(sentence)
'OPEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604  TO BUS 264888  CKT 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#) is one option:

```
import re

str_in = 'PEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 [19BVEO     345.00] TO BUS 264888 [19LRTY     345.00] CKT 1'

str_out = re.sub('\\[[^\\]]*\\]', '', str_in)
```

Prints `str_out` as

```
PEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604  TO BUS 264888  CKT 1
```

The regex pattern is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966705/2763915) for R. It will match and replace with an empty string any character sequence enclosed by square brackets in the entire string `str_in`.

It's possible that you also want to remove the extra space created from the removal of bracketed text. If you noticed, there are two spaces left from the removal instead of just one. If that's the case, you can add the following line after `re.sub`,

```
str_out = (' ').join(str_out.split('  '))
```

so `str_out` becomes,

```
PEN BRANCH FROM BUS 264604 TO BUS 264888 CKT 1
```